# Does -Dkarate.options="--tags @xyz" works for parallel runner (JUnit 5) in Karate

Tags: karate

I have been trying to overwrite the tags options in my Parallel Runner (as below) through command line `mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @hello" -Dtest=TestParallel` but it seems does not care. It run all features that marked as ignore and as defined tags here ..not overwritten. I tried with `@KarateOptions` but no use

class TestParallel {

```
@Test
void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:examples").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
}
```

However this works for a simple @karate.test - `mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @hello" -Dtest=ExampleTest`

```
class ExamplesTest {

@Karate.Test
Karate testAll() {
    return Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass());
}
```

Both of classes are on same hierarchy

What is I am missing in this command ? `mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @hello" -Dtest=TestParallel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ran into this bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1061

Can you try 0.9.6.RC1 and confirm that it is fixed ?

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas.  It did work : ). I was just about to commit my workaround to set the tag in POM systemPropertyVariables.. Will revert it .. thanks a hip